# Laravel: How to insert array data in 2 tables in database with relations

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, laravel

I need to insert array data into 2 tables. My table structure and form structure are given below. Please check and help me to insert data. I am getting an error in the browser.

**My Controller**

```php
public function prtmulti(Request $req)
{

    $maxPrId = newpr::max('prid');
    $requestData = $req->all();
    if(array_key_exists("vendor_name",$requestData))
    {
        $insertData = [];
        $uniqueData =array_unique($requestData["vendor_name"]);
        foreach ($uniqueData as $key => $value)
        {
            $maxId = $maxPrId+1;
            $insertData[] = ['prid' =>$maxId, 'vendor_id'=>$value];
            $pridarr[]=$maxId;
            $venderidarr[]=$value;
            $maxPrId = $maxPrId+1;
        }

    }
    print_r($insertData);
    print_r($requestData);
    newpr::insert($insertData);
}
```

**Required Output**

**TABLE NAME - newpr**

| id | prid | vendor_id | create_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 4 | 6 | 3 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |

**table name - pritem**

| id | pr_id | vendor_id | item_id | qty | create_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 12 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 12 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 15 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 10 | 2016-02-23 | 2016-02-23 |

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @PrashantMore why you want to insert array

Comment: @PrashantMore can you add model you create for tables.